# Asus Fonepad 7 Tablet stuck on boot logo, and can't be booted into Recovery mode

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet

My Asus Fonepad (k019/FE375) running stock Lollipop suddenly won't get past the Asus (boot logo) loading screen.

I've tried draining the battery and turning it on again, but the issue persists. I also can't access the Recovery mode.

I have done nothing -- no rooting or flashing.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Can you enter the droidboot mode by pressing the volume up and  power key, simultaneously. If yes, than you can install the firmware by using either   asus flashtool or adb command or using IntelAndroid- launcher.bat.

If you are unable to enter the droidboot mode, than you need to used the xfstk tool.